# Is there a way I can stop my laptop from turning off WiFi when I put it to sleep?

Tags: wireless-networking

Is there a way I can stop my laptop from turning off WiFi when I put it to sleep? I looked in the Device Manager but didn't see much.

Comment: What do you mean with "turning off"? Do you mean you have to reactivate the WiFi card itself after sleep, or that you have to click "Reconnect" to reconnect to the WLAN, or something else?

Comment: I disconnect from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible on Windows 7.  Just search for Wake-on-WLAN and follow the trails

[description of wake-on-Wireless-LAN operations in Win7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff571052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Technet articles](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=wowlan&ac=8)